# What is the minimum number of guesses in order to guarantee to win the prize?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, linear-programming, combinatorial-designs

Your friend will pick a $4$-letter word and you will make guesses in order to find it.

-A word can contain only the letters $A, B, C,\:\text {and} \:D$, and they can be used more than once. $(AAAA-DDDD)$.

-In your guess if at least three letters are in their correct places you will win a prize.
What is the minimum number of guesses in order to guarantee to win the prize?

Comment: Hint:  count the number of winning guesses, $W$, count the total number of guesses, $T$. The minimum is $T-W+1$

Comment: @lulu, It's for my clarification. How could you tell that this will be minimum.Because one can guess the correctly, before all wrong guesses. So, it will be smaller then your answer.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey   True!  But the OP said "guaranteed".  Let's say (inaccurately) that there are $100$ guesses, $40$ of which are correct.  If your luck is truly awful, you could guess $60$ times without every once being correct.  Granted that is improbable, but the OP did not ask about probability.

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to go through all the wrong guesses.  For instance if you guess ABCD as your first guess and its wrong, you can eliminate ABC?, AB?D, A?CD, and ?BCD words.

Comment: @paw88789, $ABCD$ is not wrong. OP says "at least" , not "at most".

Comment: @paw88789 Agreed.  I was thinking of blind guesses, as in random draws from an urn.

Comment: The question with strategy seems interesting.  Hard to see how to guarantee "mixing up" the triples in your guesses.  To be clear:  my comment referred only to blind guessing (no strategy) but I agree with the other commenters that this is not what the OP intended.

Comment: This question makes sense only if some probability/average number of guesses is involved. Otherwise min is 1.

Comment: I wondering whether this can be reduced to a domination number of some graph... Consider a graph where every vertex represents a possible 4 letter code.  Now let two vertices be adjacent if their 2 codes differ by exactly 1 spot.  Then, indeed, a dominating set would be a set of guesses where you are guaranteed success.

Comment: An upper bound is $64$ since there are $64$ combinations for the first three letters, and you can run through these in $64$ tries, with the fourth letter of each guess being arbitrary.

Comment: A lower bound is 20, since each of your guesses rule out 13 combinations (itself, and the $3\times 4$ ways of changing one of the four letters). There are 256 possibilities in total, so since $19\times 13<256$, 19 guesses cannot rule out all possibilities. Unfortunately, this is still far from the upper bound above.

Comment: @user264781: there are $16$ favorable combinations, as you only have to guess 3 letters correctly. So the lower bound is $19 = \operatorname{ceil}((256 - 16) / 13)$.

Comment: @user251257: what do you mean by favourable combination?

Comment: @user264781: if the complete correct answer is $ABCD$, then you win with any one of the guesses $?BCD$ (4 combinations), $A?CD$, $AB?D$, $ABC?$.

Comment: @user251257: you are double counting: ABCD is included in all four of those sets, you've forgotten to adjust for that.

Comment: @user264781: Oh right. Still $\operatorname{ceil}((256 - 13) / 13) = 19$. Anyway, I don't think this lower bound is realistic, as you don't known which 13 combinations (apart 1 of them) you can discard.

Comment: This question is from an ongoing competition: http://www.puzzleup.com/2015. Please see the math.SE policy on ongoing contest questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the [covering code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code) number $K_4(4,1)$. Finding such numbers are very hard problems in general.

This particular one can be found in this [paper](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-1/1/493.full.pdf), and it is equal to **24**.

The covering table is also given, I reproduce it here:

AAAA
AABB
ABAB
ABBA
ACCC
ADDD
CACD
CCDA
CDAC
DDCA
DADC
DCAD
BAAB
BABA
BBAA
BBBB
BCCC
BDDD
CBCD
CCDB
CDBC
DDCB
DBDC
DCBD

**Reference:** *Covering theorems for vectors with special reference to the case of four and five components*.
R. G. Stanton, J. D. Horton and J. G. Kalbfleisch

Comment: This question is from an ongoing competition: http://www.puzzleup.com/2015. I've flagged it for moderator attention; you might want to delete your answer before the moderators get around to it. (Here's the math.SE policy on ongoing contest questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy.)